# Keep position when moving UIView's inside of other view with XIB's

Tags: xcode, uiview, xib

I have my UI laid out in and XIB file. I realized that I need it all inside of a UIScrollView, so I drag the UIViews into the UIScrollView but all my UIView's get repositioned to the center. Is there a way to avoid this? It is extremely frustrating!!

I would do it with code, but I am forced to use XIB files.

Comment: Unfortunately scrollview layouts are frustrating for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if I understand you correctly.

Select the items in Interface Builder (Xcode) that you want inside the UIScrollView, and then go to the Editor menu, and use the menu command titled "Embed In:Scroll View".

Comment: That worked great! I never noticed that option before